# Safari not rendering images inside SVG with Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: animation, svg, safari, adobe-edge

I made an animation with Edge Animate, and I'm using some SVGs with images embedded inside (exported with Illustrator CS6). They display without problem in Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge in some Windows and Mac computers. The problem is that when I open it with Safari, the images are not rendered and only the vector part is showing. How can I solve this from Edge Animate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is present in Safari and apparently in any browser running on an Apple OS. I solved it by exporting PNGs instead of SVGs (they are lighter, too!)